# How to Get Values from a Service that Returns Promises in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call a service method in a controller. Here is my code.  ROAService.js:

```
return{
    loadROAValues:function(userId,roaId){
        var params=JSON.stringify({userId:userId,roaId:roaId});
        var promise =$http.post(url+'/'+'getROAItems',params).success(function(data)   {  
            roaDetails = data;
            $log.debug("values in service class");
            $log.debug("values in ROA");
            $log.debug(roaDetails.id);
            return roaDetails
        })
        .error(function(data){
        roaDetails = 'error';
        return roaDetails;
        });
        return promise;
    }
}
```

In controller ROA Controller:

```
$scope.getCurrentROA = function(roaObj){
    currentROA = ROAService.loadROAValues($scope.getMemberId(),roaObj.id).then(function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(response) {
       console.log("failure", response);
    });
    $log.debug("ROA id in controller class is:"+currentROA.id);
};
```

I am getting the following the output:

```
ROA id in controller class is :undefined
    values in service class
    values in ROA
    386.
```

ROA id from controller is printing before service call completes.It might be a race condition. How to keep controller wait until promise return? How to fix this race condition?

Comment: It's not a race condition. It's guaranteed to be printed before, since the service executes an asynchronous call and returns a **promise** of HTTP response, i.e. a **future** result. Read the following article: http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/. Also, success() and error() don't work like then(). Don't use them: they're deprecated.

Comment: there is no race condition;  this is how promises work.  Promises are designed to return a callback that can be executed later so that other code can continue to execute.  You created a promise, and then immediately attempt to log the result, but the result hasn't been calculated yet.  If your log were inside the `.then` block, it wouldn't execute until the promise was returned.

Comment: `success` and `error` methods **ignore return values**. Use `then` and `catch` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> How to keep controller wait until promise return?

There are two problems with the code.

- The **service factory** function is returning the data inside a `.success` method but the `.success` method **ignores return values**.
- The **controller** expects returned data but the service function returns a **promise** instead of data.

Another likely problem is that the code defines a **service class** when it should be defining a **service factory**. It is hard to tell from the question if that is the case, so in my example I will make it explicit.

### The service factory

```
angular.module("myApp",[]);

angular.module("myApp").factory("ROAService", function($http) {
    function loadROAValues(userId,roaId){
        var params = JSON.stringify({userId:userId,roaId:roaId});

        var promise = $http.post(url+'/'+'getROAItems',params);

        //chain from .then method
        promise.then( function(response) {  
            var roaDetails = response.data;
            $log.debug("values in service class");
            $log.debug("values in ROA");
            $log.debug(roaDetails.id);
            //return data for chaining
            return roaDetails;
        //process error in .catch method
        }).catch( function(error){
            var roaDetails = 'error:' + error.status;
            //throw errors for chaining
            throw roaDetails;
        });
        //return promise for chaining
        return promise;
    };
    //return service function from factory
    return { loadROAValues: loadROAValues };
});
```

In addition to the problem that the `.success` and `.error` methods **ignore return values** and return **old promises**, those methods are **deprecated**. For more information see the [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice).

### The controller

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myController",
    ['$scope', 'ROAService', function ($scope, ROAService) {
        //function returns a promise
        $scope.getCurrentROA = function(memberId, roaObj){
            //service function returns promise
            var promiseFromROA = 
                ROAService.loadROAValues(memberId, roaObj.id);
            //chain from promise
            promiseFromROA.then( function(roaDetails) {
                //$q service waits for promise to resolve
                //get values here
                $log.debug("ROA id is:"+roaDetails.id);
                //return for further chaining
                return roaDetails;
            }).catch ( function (error) {
                //process chained error
                console.log("failure: " + error);
                //throw for further chaining
                throw error;
            });
            //return promise for further chaining
            return promiseFromROA;
        };
    }]
);
```

The rule of thumb for functional programming is **always return something**. Harness the power of promises by **returning** and **chaining**.

For more information on chaining, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).